How can I optimize a vector of numbers using optim
I am trying to fit a simple model to a 6 year time series of annual observations on a population using optim with an MLE objective function to obtain the best estimates of a parameter, Prod, that changes from year to year.
The model is described by the function:
Wbio <- function(Prod) {((1-h[i])*Survwc[i]/K)*exp(-Gwc[i]) -  Catchwc[i]*exp(-Gwc[i]/2) +Prod}

and the objective function and optimization are:
Opt_Pwc <- function(Prod) {
  (1/sqrt(2*pi*(CVwc[i]^2)))*(1/exp(2*CVwc[i]^2))* (log(Survwc[i]/K)-log(Wbio(Prod)))^2}
xxx <- optim(par=Prod, fn=Opt_Pwc, method="L-BFGS-B", hessian = TRUE)

At present with this code I can estimate Prod for each year by treating each year separately.
I now want to scale this up to estimate the six values of Prod simultaneously as elements of the vector Prod[1:6] using the full time series in the model fit.
I have tried doing that by defining Prod as a vector and including it in the model as:
Prod <- vector("numeric", 6) #estimated annual production
Wbio <- function(Prod) {((1-h[i])*Survwc[i]/K)*exp(-Gwc[i]) -  Catchwc[i]*exp(-Gwc[i]/2) +Prod[i]}

And running it in a loop for  (i in 1:6)
For the optimization, I have tried using
xxx <- optim(par=Prod, fn=Opt_Pwc, method="L-BFGS-B", hessian = TRUE)

where Prod is defined as a vector and also
v <- c(Prod[1],Prod[2],Prod[3],Prod[4],Prod[5],Prod[6])
xxx <- optim(par=v, fn=Opt_Pwc, method="L-BFGS-B", hessian = TRUE)

But in both cases this produces an optimized estimate for i=1 but returns the specified starting values for Prod[2] to Prod[6].
Is there some way I can optimize the whole vector?
